# Rundown of the code process / How to set VS to show code process rundown

Tags: c, recursion

I am currently studying recursion and wanted to understand how it loops itself and wants to know how it stops by itself. I am working on a project to use putchar using recursion and confused on how it works step by step and how it knows when to stop.

If you're willing, can you explain to me step by step what's going on in the code? If not, can you teach me how to do that in VS?

Here's the code of the recursion:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printnumber(int number)
{
    if (number < 0) 
    {
       putchar('-');
       number = -number;
    }

   if (number/10)
       printnumber(number / 10);

   putchar(number%10+'0');
}

int main()
{
   int number;

   //user input
   printf("Insert an integer number: ");
   scanf_s("%d", &number);

   printnumber(number);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of `printnumber()` deals with `number < 0`, and for the rest of function including the recursive call `number >= 0` so let's split the last part into a separate function `printposnumber()`:

```
void printposnumber(unsigned int number) {
     if (number / 10) {
         printposnumber(number / 10);
     }
     putchar(number % 10 + '0');
}

void printnumber(int number) {
    if (number < 0) {
       putchar('-');
       number = -number;
    }
    printposnumber(number);
}
```

Now let's rewrite the `printposnumber()`, our only remaining recursive function, so it's more clear that there is a base case and a recursive case:

```
void printposnumber(unsigned int number) {
     // base case
     if (number < 10) {
         putchar(number + '0');
         return;
     }
 
     // recursive case
     printposnumber(number / 10);
     putchar(number % 10 + '0');    
}
```

For `printposnumber(1)` it's just like any like a regular non-recursive function call.  The condition `number < 10` is true so we run `putchar(number + '0');` and return to caller.  number + '0 converts a number between 0 and 9 to the corresponding ASCII character '0' and '9'.  In this case this means we print '1'.  Or said differently, our base case prints the first digit of a number.

For `printpostnumber(12)`, the condition `number < 10` is false, so we end up executing `printposnumber(1)` which we know from above just prints '1'.  Then remaining part is `putchar(number % 10 + '0');` which just prints the last digit of number as a string so in this case '2'.  Or said differently our recursive case prints all but the first digit of a number.

This would be a great opportunity to familiarize yourself with a debugger.  When a function is called, we push the argument onto to the stack followed by the return address.  The combination of arguments and the the return address is called a stack frame.  In our example, when we call `printnumber(123)` we push the integer 123 on the stack, followed by the the address of the `printnumber()` call in `main()` and we call `printnumber()`.  Then we do it again, we push the unsigned integer 123 onto the stack, followed by the address of the call instruction now in `printnumber()` etc.  This is how the call stack looks like in gdb when we called the base case `printposnumber(1)`:

```
#0  printposnumber (number=1) at 1.c:5
#1  0x0000555555555191 in printposnumber (number=12) at 1.c:11
#2  0x0000555555555191 in printposnumber (number=123) at 1.c:11
#3  0x00005555555551e9 in printnumber (number=123) at 1.c:20
#4  0x0000555555555227 in main () at 1.c:32
```

Notice how the return address 0x0000555555555191 is the same in stack frame #1 and #2?  That's because we are returning to the same instruction `printposnumber(number / 10);` in `printposnumber()`.  Also, note how the `number=` changes on each stack frame particular #2 through #0 where we peel off the last digit before each call (with `number / 10`).

Comment: Hi Allan, Thank you for your time replying to my question! Let me try rephrase from my understanding. Assuming that the user inputs the number 123... the 'if' is testing whether number 123 can be divided by 10. If it can, it will divide. making 123 to 12, and repeat. until 1 is left. Since 1 can't be divided by 10, it will run putchar(). But how does it remember the '23' it divide previously and run it back?

Comment: No... `if(number/10)` tests if the expression `number/10` is true, which in c can be written as `number/10 != 0` and as we know `number >= 0` that is equivalent to `number >= 10`.  For understanding, I wanted the base case first so used the fact that if(a) b else c` is the same as `if(!a) c else b`.  The inverse of `number >= 10` is `number < 10` which is what I used in `printposnumber()`.

Comment: There is no repeat other than recursion.  In your original code, we call `printnumber(123)` with the argument `number` is remembered on the stack with the value `123`.  When we recursively call `printnumber(12)` the argument `number` is still remember on the stack but on a different location and now with the value `12`.  Note, `number` is never 23!

Comment: I see, everything clicks in my head now! Thank you so much for your time and explanation. I really appreciate it... I have a hard time figuring out the logic behind recursion.